# What will the program look like if dynamic memory allocation is forbidden?

Tags: c++, operating-system, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to build lists (as well as stacks and queues), binary trees, graphs in C/C++ without dynamic memory allocation? Approaches like mannuly allocating memory from a huge static array should also be considered as dynamic memory allocating.

If possible, then how to do it?
If not, why, and if there is any other data structures that could be used to build a program conveniently? What will be a program look like?

I ask the question because I want to understand what is the exact role that dynamic memory allocation plays in programming.

I apologize if it has been illustrated in some textbook in detail.

Comment: *without dynamic memory allocation* Yes. I do it all the time in embedded systems, though more with linked lists than anything else. The main thing to watch out for is a hard limit the the size of the structures as they're sourced from a list of free nodes that have been statically allocated.

Comment: You can build any data structure using only functions.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you. but put nodes in a statically pre-allocated array should be considered as manual dynamic memory allocation in my opinion.

Comment: @molbdnilo Good idea. It looks like what some functional programming language is doing. But since I want know the exact role of dynamic memory allocation, an approach that is *similar* to conventional C/C++ programming (rather functional programming) will be better.

Comment: Well, a conventional GUI human interface is probably out:(

Comment: ...and operating systems:)